# Bulk renaming using regexp

Tags: regex

I am using Bulk Rename Utility to change the name of a lot of files. The files have a name similar to this one:

```
Albert_Silva-MR11_0.dcm
```

On each folder, there are files with the same name, only changing the last number, for example:

```
Albert_Silva-MR11_13.dcm
```

So, I was trying to find the regex expression to match everything until the last _ character in the file, in order to substitute it by "slice". In the example, "Albert_Silva-MR11_0.dcm" would then become "slice_0.dcm". Note that some file names have more than two ocurrences of _, so looking for the second _ wouldn't be valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use greedy matching:

```
^.*_(\d+\.dcm)
```

And replace with `slice_$1`.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/oK2zZ9/2)

The `^` can be redundant (depending on how the tool handles the regex), it forces a match at the beginning of the string. `.*` matches all characters to the end, and then backtracking finds the character at the position before the final `_`, and matches that text. `(\d+\.dcm)` matches and captures the last digit(s) and extension that will be put back with the help of the `$1` (or `\1`) back-reference.

Comment: Note that anchoring at the end makes no sense in this case since `digits`+`.`+`.dcm` will surely mark the end of string with these contents, and checking the end of string counts as 1 more step.

Comment: Yes, this works. I always just upvote, I hadn't noticed the checkmark for accepting the answer until you mentioned it now. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Anchor at the end my friend:

```
(_\d+\.dcm)$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uV1nW0/2)