# bulk rename utility : regex expression : formatting : filenames

Tags: regex

Finding [Bulk renaming using regexp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32386411/bulk-renaming-using-regexp), and many other regexp utility help locations through out the web.

I have come up with.

```
(.*?)([0-9][0-9])(.*?)([0-9][0-9])(.*)
```

to be replaced by

```
Whatever - S\2E\4 -\5
```

To be used when renaming all my dvd backups
When I mess up the naming scheme over the years sometimes there was only 4 seasons sometimes there was more than ten and so sometimes i used 1x01 as naming schema instead of 01x01.
SO Im looking for a if then else statement to match the 
if 01 then 01 if 1 then 01 in the following samples
so sometimes i named files
1x01
01x01
s1e1
s1e01
and my above regex matches mose of the times except for the single number versus two digits....

Help.... LOL

Comment: What language will you be running this regex in?  Please offer a separate list of possible inputs and your expected output for each.  This will make your question easier to understand.

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/HH0a7c/1, does it work for you?

Comment: (.*?)([0-9][0-9]?)([xe])([0-9][0-9]?)(.*) did not work.

Comment: @Jeff can you give an example where your last regex failed? Did it not match at all, or did it match wrongly?

Comment: I have a list of files now to test upon if you will. 'Show S01E01 HDTV blah blah' 'Show S1E02 HDTV blah blah' I type in '(.*?)([0-9][0-9]?)([xe])([0-9][0-9]?)(.*)' followed by replace with 'Show - S\2E\4 - ' It does not match either one. I use '(.*?)([0-9][0-9])([exXE])([0-9][0-9])(.*)' and it only matches the 'S01E01' so I tried '(.*?)([0-9][0-9]?)([exXE])([0-9][0-9]?)(.*)' and that matched both so now how to add the leading 0 if not there?

Answer (score 0):

Replace `[0-9][0-9]` with `[0-9][0-9]?`, or `[0-9]{1,2}`. The `?` means the second `[0-9]` is optional; the `{1,2}` means do `[0-9]` repeatedly, but no fewer than 1 and no more than 2 times.

I don't know whether you want to add/remove leading zeroes. If you want to remove them, use something like `0?([1-9]?[0-9])`. For adding leading zeroes, I don't know exactly without knowing what regex engine you're using. You could probably do it with a separate search-and_replace.

Comment: neither version of the above works I have also tried | or statements ....

Comment: Bulk rename utility 64 bit version 3.0.0.1 TGRMN software